# Constructing OR gate with OT

Tags: multiparty-computation, oblivious-transfer

I am constructing a two-party OR gate and trying to do this with oblivious transfer. Yet I am very new to oblivious transfer, wishing to know whether the following construction makes sense.

Goal: Alice inputs a random bit $a$, Bob inputs a random bit $b$, and Bob outputs the logical OR bit $a\oplus b$.

Construction via 1-out-of-2 OT: Alice inputs $m_0 = a, m_1 = 1$, Bob inputs $c = b$, and finally Bob returns $m_c$. Obviously, Bob returns $0$ iff $a=b=0$ and returns $1$ otherwise.

My first confusion is could I fix $m_1$ as a constant? Secondly, the probability of Bob knowing $a$ is $1$ when $b=0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ when $b=1$, respectively. It seems the output (i.e., $a \oplus b$) leaks Alice's secret $a$ in a combinatorial probability of $\frac{3}{4}$. Should it be a valid OT?

Comment: Hey, is it a class homework? First Google for it and I got: https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/cs598dk/fa2019/Files/lecture07.pdf

Comment: @CryptoLearner Many thanks for your help! Indeed, the construction in my question is very the same as the AND protocol in the lecture you referred. Yet I'm still confusing how this is valid? Given that Bob can always know Alice's input $a$ as long as $b=0$, should it not be a leakage of Alice's input $a$?